# Read a (bad?) id field in hibernate/ nhibernate

Tags: c#, hibernate, postgresql, nhibernate, logging

I am writing to a database log for my application.  One of the fields in the table is `userprofile_id` which references a username.  This is a nullable field, as some stuff gets written to the log without a user context.

In NHibernate, to collect the username, I really can't look at the reference column though, but rather the referenced object.  In most cases this is fine; if it's null, there's just no username.  So when trying to display the username associated with the log, I actually have to reference the `Log.User.UserName`.

The twist comes in in that I have a system account with a rigid set of permissions and no associated user profile to invoke automated tasks through the api interface.  It writes to the log as `userprofile_id` *system*, which does not exist in my `UserProfiles` table.

To make this work, I had to remove the foreign key between the logs table and the `UserProfiles` table, but the data is logged, and NHibernate doesn't seem to care.  It just reports the `UserProfile` object as null, which is technically correct.

I would actually like to see the text of the `userprofile_id` field through NHibernate though, even though it won't join to the `UserProfiles` table, so I can differentiate the log entries that have no user context and those that have a system function context.

Is there a way, in (N)Hibernate, to request the value of the reference field, rather than the associated object?  Or am I going to have to do something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another property to your log entry class and map it as a property to the userprofile_id column.

That said, I think you should really handle the sytem account like all other accounts and have its permissions stored in the database.

**EDIT**

To illustrate the workaround:

```
public class Log
{
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    //Add this property
    public virtual string UserProfileId { get; set; }

    public string UserProfileName
    {
        get { return User != null ? User.Name : UserProfileId; }
    }
}
```

And map it to the column:

```
public class LogMap : ClassMap<Log>
{
    public LogMap()
    {
        //Map it with this:
        Map(l => l.UserProfileId).Column("userprofile_id");

        //Don't change the existing mappings
        References(l => l.User);//...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elucidate what you mean.

Comment: Just to give you some relevant sample code: are you using XML mapping files? Is `Log.User` property mapped using a many-to-one association using the `userprofile_id` column?

Comment: Well, I'm using Fluent NHibernate.  but if you could explain in terms of xml files, I'm sure I could translate it.

Comment: I prefer FluentNHibernate :)
Is `Log.User` mapped with `References(l => l.User).Column("userprofile_id")`?

Comment: Something similar.  I think I am using `PropertyRef` as the username is not the primary key of the `UserProfiles` table.

Comment: This looks like it might work.  I will check it this afternoon and give feedback.

Comment: I had to do this a little differently, but it did work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If a Log's userprofile_id is null, then Log.User will be null. You can check it through the referenced property like,

```
Log.User==null
```

or query like this,

```
session.Query<Log>().Where(l=>l.User==null).ToList()
```

This will fetch the entities not having Users (Logs with userprofile_id is null).

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.  This is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes I did not first, sorry, but now I understood. If I were you, I would insert a row for system user into the table UserProfiles so that the data would be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on not-found=ignore is considered a feature designed to help with legacy databases - not something that should be designed into new systems. There are some negative performance aspects. It would be better to make sure you have the proper foreign key, or alternatively not map it as a reference in NHibernate at all (i.e. remove navigability from Log to User) - instead you would call you user lookup method if you need more than the username itself.